# How can I stop Microsoft Excel or Word from starting automatically?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, boot, windows-registry

When I start my computer, either Microsoft Excel or Word starts automatically with an empty page. I think it's the program I've opened last. I've removed and reïnstalled Office completely, this didn't help.

Places I've checked:

- Task Manager > Startup
- These folders on my computer:

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
%HOMEPATH%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

- These places in the registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

Nowhere is there any trace of Excel or Word. Still, when I start my computer, Excel/Word does too. How can I stop this from happening without removing Office?

The version is Office ProPlus from Office 365.

Update:
@SavGuard, pointed me to autoruns.exe from sysinternal tools. It found the following autorun entry:

```
ClickToRunSvc   Microsoft Office Click-to-Run Service: ‪Manages resource coordination, background streaming, and system integration of Microsoft Office products and their related updates. This service is required to run during the use of any Microsoft Office program, during initial streaming installation and all subsequent updates.‬  Microsoft Corporation   c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\officeclicktorun.exe  2019-06-26 02:28
```

I've disabled this and rebooted, but this didn't fix the problem.

Comment: What happens, if you remove the content of the startup folders? Is there anything there that could start Excel (ex: a script or something)?

Comment: There's nothing there.

Comment: Pls convert to a comment. (not enough Reputation) Have u check the system with autoruns.exe from sysinternal tools?
Have the emtpy sheet a name?
What happend if you edit and save? It is next time empty?

Comment: @JohnStoneman,, which Version of Windows you are using I guess windows 10 !!

Comment: @RajeshS, I'm using Windows 10 Pro, version 1903.

Comment: @SavGuard, thanks for pointing me to autoruns.exe. It found the following entries for Office, but nothing for Excel specifically:
\Microsoft\Office\Office Automatic Updates 2.0 Microsoft Office Click-to-Run Client Microsoft Corporation c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\officec2rclient.exe 2019-06-26 02:37 

\Microsoft\Office\Office ClickToRun Service Monitor Microsoft Office Click-to-Run Client Microsoft Corporation c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\clicktorun\officec2rclient.exe 2019-06-26 02:37

Comment: @JohnStoneman,, try this,, Press `Windows Start Button`, search the `msconfig.exe` and RUN it, Click `Startup Tab` & hit `Open Task Manager,` you find `Startup Item`, select it and below find `Disable` button ,, hit & finish with `Ok`,, restart Windows,, **confirm if this works, then I post it as Answer** !

Comment: @Rajesh, Windows 10 doesn't use msconfig anymore to manage what starts up, it uses the Task manager. As I described in my first post, that was the first thing I checked. There is no entry for Office or Excel there.

Comment: @JohnStoneman,, it uses I've tried so far, once you search it and if found RUN !

Comment: Rename `excel.exe` and reboot, to see if you get an informative error message.

Comment: This does not sound like it is caused by Microsoft Office. Have you checked the setting in “Settings > Accounts > Sign-in Options” that says (among onther things) “reopen my apps after restart”? See here: https://www.howtogeek.com/396884/how-to-stop-windows-10-from-reopening-your-previous-applications-after-restarting-your-pc/

Comment: @StarCat, yes, this worked! But still, even with this setting enabled, how can I stop Word/Excel from starting? If you post it as answer, I'll mark it as the right one.